# default timezone is wrong while saving to database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime-format

I am trying to save the date and time to database in `DATETIME` format.
In my server i have timezone set to `Default timezone - Asia/Kolkata` If i display the time

```
`$dt2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $dt2;`
```

like this, it is displaying properly. But saved time in database is wrong. For ex: Now it is 2018-03-31 16:41:20,  but while saving database it saves `2018-03-31 11:02:12`. 
I am saving like this

```
`dtime=NOW()`,
```

Comment: `NOW()` will take mysql time stamp. it will not dependent on php configuration

Comment: Yes, i got it solved!. Instead of `NOW()` i have used `$dt2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $dt2;` to save to database

Comment: MySQL has it's own Datetime settings in the `my.cnf` If I remember correctly.  By the By, PHP may also run a separate `.ini` for the `CLI` command line interface.

Comment: Yes. As i use shared hosting, i had to create .ini of my own and changed the timezone over there

Answer (score 0):

NOW() will take MySQL timestamp, it will not take php configuration time.